# Comparar strings dentro de arquivo em C++

Tags: c++

Boa tarde a todos, o problema é o seguinte. Tenho dados dentro do arquivo txt e quando no programa é solicitado para o usuário digitar login e senha para a comparação, simplesmente fica em um loop. Será que alguém pode me dar uma luz por favor? Já pesquisei bastante e ainda não consegui resolver meu problema! Abaixo vou deixar o código.

```
void entrar(void) { 
usu.open("usu_admin.txt", ios::in);

if(!usu) { 
    cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar" 
         << endl << endl << "Usuario admin nao cadastrado!" 
         << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento...";
    
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    
    system("cls");
        
    cad_admin();
} 
else { 
    while(getline(usu, linha)) { 
        cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar" 
             << endl << "Login admin: ";
        
        cin >> l;
        cin.clear();
        
        cout << "Senha admin: ";
        
        for(i=0;i<6;i++) { 
            cin.clear();
            s[i]=getch ();
            putchar ('*');
        } 
        
        cout << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento..."; 
        
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        
        char* linTemp;
        
        linTemp=&linha[0];
        
        if((strcmp(l, linTemp)==0) && (strcmp(s, linTemp)==0)) {
            system ("cls");
            
            menu ();
        }
    }
}

usu.close();
```

}

Comment: poste um programa inteiro, compilável. Ajude os outros a ajudarem você

Comment: Olá, segue o código. Desde já agradeço pela resposta. Não consegui postar ele da maneira correta de código. Mas todas a linhas dele estão presentes...

Comment: :) ficou engraçado. Deve dar pra juntar. Para ficar mais fácil pra você pode usar ``` antes e depois do código. O sinal de crase, não a apóstrofe, 3 vezes no início da linha, antes e depois e o editor Mark-Down entende como código o que estáo no meio. Também pode copiar o código todo para o post, selecionar a primeira letra e ir descendo com o teclado, mantendo shift apertado, de modo a selecionar o programa todo, e depois aperar control-k. Mais chato mas funciona também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include <conio.h>
#include

using namespace std;

void comeco(void);

void entrar(void);

void cad_admin(void);

void menu(void);

static char inicio, l[15], login[15], senha[7], s[7];
static int i, cont=0;
static string linha;

fstream usu, usu_geral;

int main() {
comeco();

```
return 0;
```

}

void comeco(void) {
while(inicio!='2') {
cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0" << endl << endl
<< "[1] - Entrar" << endl << "[2] - Sair" << endl
<< endl << "Selecione sua opcao: ";

```
    cin >> inicio;
    cin.clear();
    
    switch(inicio) {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
        
            entrar();
        break;
        
        case '2':
            system("cls");
        
            cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0" << endl
                << endl << "Obrigado por utilizar o sistema!";
        
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    }
    
    system("cls");
}
```

}

void entrar(void) {
usu.open("usu_admin.txt", ios::in);

```
if(!usu) {
    cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar" 
         << endl << endl << "Usuario admin nao cadastrado!" 
         << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento...";
    
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    
    system("cls");
        
    cad_admin();
} 
else { 
    while(getline(usu, linha)) {
        cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar" 
             << endl << "Login admin: ";
        
        cin >> l;
        cin.clear();
        
        cout << "Senha admin: ";
        
        for(i=0;i<6;i++) { 
            cin.clear();
            s[i]=getch ();
            putchar ('*');
        } 
        
        cout << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento..."; 
        
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        
        char* linTemp;
        
        linTemp=&linha[0];
        
        if((strcmp(l, linTemp)==0) and (strcmp(s, linTemp)==0)) {
            system ("cls");
            
            menu ();
        }
    } 
}

usu.close();
```

}

void cad_admin(void) {
usu.open("usu_admin.txt", ios::out);
usu_geral.open("usu_geral.txt", ios::out);

```
cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Cadastrar"
     << endl << endl << "Login admin: ";
     
cin >> l;
cin.clear();

usu << l << endl;
usu_geral << l << endl;

cout << endl;

do {
    cout << "Senha admin, numerica, 6 digitos!" << endl
        << "Informar senha: ";
     
     for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        cin.clear();
        senha[i]=getch();
        putchar('*');
     } 
     
   cout << endl << "Confirmar senha: ";
     
     for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        cin.clear();
        s[i]=getch();
        putchar('*');
    } 
    
    if(strcmp(s, senha)!=0) {
        cout << endl << endl << "As senhas nao coincidem!";
        
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        
        cout << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento...";
        
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
        
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
} while(strcmp(s, senha)!=0);

cout << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento...";

this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));

cout << endl << endl << "Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!";

this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));

usu << senha << endl << endl;
usu_geral << senha << endl << endl;

usu.close();
usu_geral.close();
```

}

void menu(void) {
cout << "Acesso realido com sucesso!" << endl << endl;

```
system("pause");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    void comeco(void);
    void entrar(void);
    void cad_admin(void);
    void menu(void);
 
    static char inicio, l[15], login[15], senha[7], s[7]; static int i, cont = 0; 
    static string linha;
    
    fstream usu, usu_geral;
    
    int main() {
        comeco();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Recomendo muito evitar esse tipo de construção.

- uma função `void f(void)` em geral é um desastre. Um buraco negro.
  Nada entra, já que não tem argumentos, nada sai já que não retorna nada. Use argumentos, retorne valores, nunca use nada global.
- `main()` é, bem, `main()`. Quando acabar acabou o programa. E seu programa tem um único módulo. Qual a razão de declarar algo como `static` nesse contexto?  Que diferença pode fazer?

Um comando desses

```
        cout << "Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar"
            << endl << endl << "Usuario admin nao cadastrado!"
            << endl << endl << "Aguarde um momento...";
```

é a mesma coisa que esse

```
        cout << "\
Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar\
\n\
\n\
Usuario admin nao cadastrado!\
\n\
\n\
Aguarde um momento...\n";
```

que é a mesma coisa que esse

```
        cout << "\
Sistema de cadastro | Infra.V.1.0 - Entrar\n\n\
Usuario admin nao cadastrado!\n\n\
Aguarde um momento...\n";
```

Evite usar `endl` sem necessidade e mesmo esses `<<` todos. Não é preciso.

Seu programa parece ter algo errado com os `\n` apenas. Ao ler a senha notei que ainda tem um `\n` na frente do valor.

Evite `conio.h`. É difícil justificar em um ambiente como C++ o uso de uma biblioteca dos aos '80 que vinha em 2 diskettes de 1.44MB JUNTO com o compilador e o IDE Borland Turbo C. E é derivada de outra biblioteca que vinha no Apple II!

Não use `system()`. É proibida em muitos lugares, insegura e nada faz: apenas envia uma string para o shell. Não vai aprender nada e não vai estar fazendo nada. `system("entrar em orbita")` não cria um programa para a corrida espacial :)